# Github pages shows only the readme after deploying NextJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, next.js, github-pages

I made this basic e-commerce web app using next js ( using nextjs 14 ) and I wanted to deploy it with github pages.

I followed a tutorial on youtube and I tried deploying it by using gh-page branch and github actions and both end up showing only the readme when you visit the website. I did change the branch from the main to gh-pages at the source and still the same. Can anyone help me ?

[Github Pages Link](https://noelkasemi.github.io/strength-palace) ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzvyB.png))

[My Github Repo](https://github.com/noelkasemi/strength-palace)

I tried deploying with Github actions and got the same result. I tried with branch and I did use both the main one and the gh-pages one and again the same result. Thanks in advance to anyone who might help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Github pages but a preliminary look showed that it needs static app to run. Your repo contains just the app without any build.

Change your `next.config.js` from:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

to :

```
 /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: "exports", // lightweight but no dynamic routes & api support
    // output: "standalone", // bulkier but supports dynamic routes & api
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Then build your app using:

```
npm run build
```

It'll generate a build folder, try again with that newly generated build folder. Make sure your paths are correctly configured to that.